# How to set marker color according to a column in leaflet R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I need to make make circles different colors based on `if` condition. I added `if` statement to `color=` parameter but all circles are coloured only in one color, so it'doesn't work. I base on standard `quakes` dataset and need to differ colours based on `depth>300` condition. I tried to use `lapply` but not sure if I do it correctly: `lapply(if(coords$depth > 300) 'red' else 'green',htmltools::HTML)`. Anyways, do you have any idea how to make it possible?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(htmlwidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
   leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
   coords <- quakes %>%
      sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326)

     output$map <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
     leaflet::leaflet() %>%         
       leaflet::addTiles() %>%
       leaflet::setView(172.972965,-35.377261, zoom = 4) %>%
       leaflet::addCircleMarkers(
         data = coords,
         stroke = FALSE,
         color = if(coords$depth > 300) 'red' else 'green',
         radius = 6)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

data(quakes)

quakes[1:20, ] %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat,
    popup = ~ as.character(mag),
    label = ~ as.character(mag),
    color = ~ ifelse(depth > 300, "red", "green")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, smart. In my real app though I pass `data` in `addCircleMarkers`, that's why I'm looking for a solution which dynamically set color in `color` parameter (lapply? apply?)

Comment: Do you want to have teh threshold (currently fixed to 300) set e.g. by a slider? Does `data` change over time?

Comment: Could be a slider or not, for now I need to know hot to dynamically set colors to `color`. I guess I would need to use some type of `apply`. And yes, data change over time (reactive)

Comment: Do you want the user to define which color the circles with a lower value should have? Please elaborate "dynamically set colors to `color`'' Or do you want to have a gradient e.g. shades of red depending on depth?. Just replace `quakes[1:20,]` with e.g.  `data()` to make it reactive.

Comment: By 'dynamically' I mean not adding new column using `mutate` but making calculations in `color` parameter. That's why I added `if` statement to `color` in my example. I don't want user to define color. Just red for > 300 and green < 300. And I need to add this `if` statement directly in `color` parameter. In my real, big app this is the only solution for me.

Comment: Since the function `addCircleMarkers` accepts formulas for the color option, you can put the expression there as well. I revised my answer. I guess, the `apply` aka map stuff is handled inside the leaflet function. That's why it accepts formulas.

Comment: In fact ,it works! Thanks! But I'm wondering now why `if(depth > 300) 'red' else 'green'` didn't work and `ifelse(depth > 300, "red", "green")` works?

Comment: `ifelse` is a vectorized function.